# in vs at + gerund

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

Consider the following examples :

1. Would You be interested *in* buying a ticket
2. Jerry is very good *at* playing drum

The first sentence uses '*in*' before the gerund while the second one uses '*at*'. Why would that happen, are there some patterns that we could use to apply '**in**' and '*at*' before the gerund. Is it wrong If I replace *in* with *at* on the second example?

Comment: It depends more on the adverb than the activity. Whilst *interested* takes *in*, *good* takes *at*. One could equally well say *Would you be interested in playing drum*; or *Jerry is good at buying tickets*.

Comment: Thanks, so they are just the same?

Comment: You have to look up a dictionary and it explains well. Each preposition has its own function. I would advise you to visit this [site](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) and post questions there.

Comment: So you mean, 'good at',  'interested in' , they are a unit of word?

Comment: @hansf. That is not to say that those words will not be followed by other prepositions. One might, for example say *I would be interested to find out where he is*. Or *John is good for running errands*. It means something slightly different if you say *John is good at running errands*. I am thinking you may find our sister site English Language Learners more suitable to your needs.

Comment: @WS2 and Rathony, oke Thank you, I'll ask there.

Comment: @WS2 adjective.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok - adjective!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some adjectives select specific prepositions as complement.

"Interested" selects "in", and "good" selects "at".

Others like "amused", "hurt" and "distressed" select "by", while "adept", "hopeless" and "talented" for example also select "at".

Most often (for a given sense of the adjective) they are not interchangeable, so you can't say *"Would you be interested at buying a ticket", or *"Jerry is very good in playing drum".

I would suggest you buy one of the many books available that deal specifically with prepositions and their uses.

Comment: Though I agree with your answer, not many books discuss about specific pair of 'in, at, etc', only discussing about 'when you use prepositions with a verb, add -ing to the verb', something like that. And Thank You for your answer